# Navigating specific dirs in filter with os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I am aware that I can remove dirs from os.walk using something along the lines of

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/dir'):
    ignore = ['dir1', 'dir2']
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in ignore]
```

I want to do the opposite of this, so only keep the dirs in list. Ive tried a few variations but to no avail. Any pointers would be appreciated.

The dirs i am interested in are 2 levels down, so I have taken on the comments and created global variables for the sub levels and am using the following Code.

**Expected Functionality**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(global_subdir):
keep = ['dir1', 'dir2']
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d in keep]
for filename in files:
    print os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but have you tried changing "not in" to "in"?

Comment: yes I have. I have updated my question to hope explain abit better

Comment: Did you try `dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d in keep]` ? what did you get?

Comment: why not the opposite `[k for k in keep if k in dirs]`

Comment: This seems trivial, so what have you *actually tried* and what was the problem with it?

Comment: yes, I agree seems trivial but I cant seem to get the functionality I am after

Comment: all of the above comments have been tried, none print the filenames in the example

Comment: Can you give examples of what you tried, what you directory structure looked like, what you expected as output and what you got instead?

Comment: Anand, I did try that yes but no filenames are printed. The dirs im trying to keep are sub dirs of the root 2 levels down.

Comment: Do you really want to `for filename in files:` instead of `for dirnames in dirs:`?

Comment: Yes lol, if os.walk gets dirs in keep, walk them and print filenames

Comment: Anand S Kumar made a really helpful comment in a deleted answer. I copy/paste it here: `if you just need those dirs 2 levels below the root, why start at root? Why not start one level above the dir you want?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments of a deleted answer -

> As mentioned already, this doesnt work. The dirs in keep are 2 levels sub root. Im guessing this is causing the problem

The issue is that the directory one level above your required directory would not be traversed since its not in your `keep` list, hence the program would never reach till your required directories.

The best way to solve this would be to start `os.walk` at the directory that is just one level above your required directory.

But if this is not possible (like maybe the directories one level above the required one is not known before traversing) or ( the required directories have different directories one level above). And what you really want is to just avoid looping through the files for directories that are not in the `keep` directory.

A solution would be to traverse all directories, but loop through the `files` only when `root` is in the `keep` list (or set for better performance). Example -

```
keep = set(['required directory1','required directory2'])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(global_subdir):
    if root in keep:
        for filename in files:
            print os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Comment: Anand can you give me any resources to try understand the comprehension statement?

Comment: Isn't `any(x == d for x in keep)` the same as `d in keep`, though? For some reason the latter doesn't work for the OP.